# Create array formula in excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I tried to create an array formula using index small row combination. The formula I tried to use is a simple one where it should create an array when two criteria are met and should me give all the AN values for Cat1: 22 and Cat2: a I can't find the error in the formula.

The first sheet name is RawData and the second Test.

Here is the formula

`=IFERROR(INDEX(RawData!C:C, SMALL(IF(1=((--($A$2=RawData!A:A))*(--($B$2=RawData!B:B))), ROW(RawData!C:C)-2,""), ROW()-2)),"")`

[image]

[image]

The result was a NUM! Error when I ignored the iferror

Comment: I think you should try to use `FILTER` and `SORT`. Also, beware that when you select whole columns you also select header (which is what first row seems to be in your case) of each of them.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk I just removed the -2 which solved it for me thanks for the hint